# Elasticsearch filter on nested set

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm having trouble figuring out how to filter on nested sets. I have this in my index:

```
PUT /testing

PUT /testing/_mapping/product
{
   "product": {
      "properties": {
         "features": { "type": "nested" }
      }
   }
}

POST /testing/product
{
   "productid": 123,
   "features": [
      {
         "name": "Weight",
         "nameslug": "weight",
         "value": "10",
         "valueslug": "10-kg"
      },
      {
         "name": "Weight",
         "nameslug": "weight",
         "value": "12",
         "valueslug": "12-kg"
      }
   ]
}
```

I need to filter on `value` but I get the `valueslug` from the url. So far I have the following code:

```
POST _search
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "filter": [
            {
               "nested": {
                  "path": "features",
                  "query": {
                     "bool": {
                        "filter": [
                           {
                              "range": {
                                 "features.value": { "gte": ???  }
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

The difficult part is resolving the `valueslug` to the actual `value`. I have looked into Script Query using `doc_value`, but the problem with that is that it is executed within the current nested document. It would be possible by execution two queries, but I am trying to avoid that (if possible).

I get the feeling that the solution lies in the way the documents should be structured, but I have no clue how I could structure this any different...

I hope anyone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would not use this kind of mapping, I'd rather use a parent-child mapping, so product would have several children features, and then filtering on them will be much easier, see this link for more info: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child-mapping.html

Comment: Thank you for your respone. While I do agree that filtering would be easier with a parent-child mapping, I do not really grasp how this would make the resolution of the slug value to the actual value possible. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: The simplest would be to pick the valueslug from your url, convert it to a value, then feed it to elasticsearch. I'm afraid that as far as I know, you cannot convert such a string to an integer on the fly with elasticsearch.